# Yarn remove old package (that has security vulnerability)?

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

Hi I am new to `yarn` (and `React.js` for that matter) but I am maintaining a system with it.

Recently I received a [security alert](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-10747#vulnCurrentDescriptionTitle) from NIST (via GitHub) that a package `set-value`, at version 2.0.0, needs to be updated

So I updated it using this command:

```
$ yarn add set-value@2.0.1
```

But after that, I saw that `yarn.lock` still had reference to `2.0.0`, with a line like this

```
set-value@2.0.1, set-value@^2.0.0:
```

I thought that was okay, but was proven wrong -- because I still received another security alert from GitHub one day later

Then I tried another upgrade, this time to `3.0.1`

```
$ yarn upgrade set-value@3.0.1
```

Now I still see, in `yarn.lock`, a reference to `2.0.0`, with a line:

```
set-value@^2.0.0
```

I then tried these

```
$ yarn remove set-value
$ yarn add set-value
```

But the line mentioned above about `set-value@^2.0.0` is still in `yarn.lock`

I don't know if this is okay or not to GitHub (will have to wait for one day to see the result).  What do you think?

Comment: you can delete the lock file it will auto generate again.Your yarn.lock file is auto-generated and should be handled entirely by Yarn. As you add/upgrade/remove dependencies with the Yarn CLI, it will automatically update your yarn.lock file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try deleting yarn.lock file and install the dependencies again.

`yarn install --check-files`

yarn.lock is auto-generated on `yarn install` which should update **set-value** to version **2.0.1**

hope this helps, Happy coding!!!